# How to change <td> tag into <input> active tag in react.js using button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-frontend

In the given code below, there is **td** tag which includes **input** tag inside it. I have disabled it initially so that the user can't change the data. Because of this if the data inside it is more than 2 lines or something then all of it will not be visible.

**1)** I want to make data fit as per its length, like 'textarea'.
**2)** In the end, there is an "Edit" button, when I click on that button all the **td** tags should become **input** tags. Therefore I should be able to edit the data inside it. Please can anyone help me with this? I want to achieve this using react.js Thank you in advance.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import '../src/tabledata.css';

  function TableData() {
    const [data, getData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
},[])

const fetchData = () => {
  fetch("/api")
  .then((res) =>
  res.json())

  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    getData(response);
  })
}

function edit() {


  
}

return (
  // whole body
  <div className='body'>
    <h1 className='heading'>GCP DOCUMENT AI DATA</h1> {/* heading */}

    <div> {/* container for table */}
    <div className='tbl'> {/* div for table inside container */}
    <tbody>
      <tr> {/* headings in table */}
        <th>Keys</th>
        <th>Values</th>
      </tr>

      {data.map((item,i) => (
        <tr key={i}> {/* 1st column keys and 2nd column values */}
          <td>{item.keys}</td>
          <td><input className='tdValueInput' type="text" value={item.values} disabled/></td>
        </tr>
      ))}
      <div> {/* div for buttons */}
        <input type="submit" className='bttn-edit' value="Edit" onClick={edit}/>
        <input type="submit" className='bttn-approve' value="Approve"/>
      </div>
    </tbody>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
);
  }

export default TableData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few things:

1. turn form into edit mode needs a react state

```
const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState(false);
```

2. you need to 'activate' edit mode in edit function with

```
setEditing(true);
```

3. you need to change rendering of `<td>` vs  `<input>` based on `isEditing` variable

```
{isEditing ? <td>{item.values}</td> : <td><input value={item.values} /></td>}
```

4. you need to add `onChange` prop for input to change edited data

```
<input value={item.values} onChange={(e) => item.values = e.target.value}  />
```

You have invalid HTML structure - missing `<table>` and mixing `<div>` with `<tr>` element on same level